# Display setting in Adjust for TV Mode screws up stylus pen cursor position - solved though

Tags: display, touchpad, 19.04

I had an issue with the cursor for a Sony Stylus Pen on my X360 2500 Ryzen laptop.
The cursor showed incorrectly.
Checking OFF the setting for adjust for TV solved this problem. 
I suspect that the option does allow for changing the screen resolution (or zoom or whatever it does).
I had this matrix with the problem from 
xinput --list-props 23
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): -0.500000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000, -0.923867, 0.923867, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000

and when normal again

Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): -0.500000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000

so I probably would have needed to correct it by
xinput set-prop "ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix

more details on the problem

In the middle of the screen it was ok, to the right the cursor was 1cm to the left of the pen, and to the right the cursor was 1cm to the right. 
I noticed that somehow I had Adjust for TV set in the display properties of Ubuntu 19.04. I had checked this for the second monitor TV but do not recall doing so for the laptop screen. I have been experimenting with xrandr though.

Answer (score 0):

Press super key
type Display
Go to Screen Display Properties
Select affected Display
Toggle off Display for TV if it is on.